Extract data from word to excel
I am attempting to make a list of things in excel and then search for them in a word document.  Once the item is found, I am looking to extract a specific number of before and after the word found and display it in a new sheet of the excel document.
Been trying to crack this but via message boards and YouTube.  But keeping getting and error that highlights “line 4: Dim oWord As Word.Application”
Sub LocateSearchItem()
    Dim shtSearchItem As Worksheet
    Dim shtExtract As Worksheet
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim WordNotOpen As Boolean
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oRange As Word.Range
    Dim LastRow As Long ' last row with data in shtSearchItem
    Dim CurrRowShtSearchItem As Long ' current row in shtSearchItem
    Dim CurrRowShtExtract As Long ' current Row in sht Extract
    Dim myPara As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set oWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    
    If Err Then
        Set oWord = New Word.Application
        WordNotOpen = True
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo Err_Kandler
    
    oWord.Visible = True
    oWord.Activate
    Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("icloud\desktop\PCL Shell.docx") ' file location
    
    Set shtSearchItem = ThisWorkbook.worsheets(1)
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count < 2 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add After! * shtSearchItem
    End If
    Set shtExtract = ThisWorkdook.Worksheets(2)
    
    LastRow = shtSearchItem.UsedRange.Rows(shtSearchItem.UsedRange.Rows.conut).Row
    
    For CurrRowShtSearchItem = 2 To LastRow
        Set oRange = oDoc.Range
        With oRange.Find
            .Text = shtSearchItem.Cells(CurrRowShetSearchItem, 1).Text
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            While oRange.Find.Execute = True
                oRange.Select
                myPara = oDocRange(0, oWord.Selection.Characters(39).Range.End).Characters.Count
                
                CurrRowShtExtract = CurrRowShtExtract + 1
                
                shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 1).Value = .Text
                shetExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 2).Value = myPara
                shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 3) = oDoc.Characters(myPara).Range
                
                oRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                
            Wend
        End With
    Next CurrRowShtSearchItem
    
    If WordNotOpen Then
        oWord.Quit
    End If
    
    'Release object reference
    
    Set oWord = Nothing
    Set oDoc = Nothing
    
    Exit Sub
    
Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Word caused a problem. " & Err.Description, vbCrritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    If WordNotOpen Then
    
End Sub

Not very experienced with VBA.  I tried changing from oWord. To WdApp but nothing changed.
I give credit to most of it to https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Sthk1PzfT4M&pp=ygUrU2VhcmNoIHdvcmQgZG9jdW1lbnQgYW5kIHB1bGwgZGF0YSB0byBFeGNlbA%3D%3D but doesn’t look like he is answer comments anymore.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

VBA and VBScript are two totally different and distinct languages. They are not the same just because they start with VB, any more than a cat, a car, and a carrot are related because they all start with CA. You used a VBScript tag, but mention VBA in the post body. Which one are you actually using?

In Excel VBA project by clicking the Tools > References, check Microsoft Word x.0 Object Library to add a reference.

What taller wrote: You need to tell the Excel VBA compiler about the Word objects. This is done by adding the reference to the Word library. In the linked video, it is shown at 2:29

Aside from your reference problem - you've written On Error GoTo Err_Kandler.  The label at the bottom of the code is Err_Handler.

Thanks for all responses and help.  I was not aware of differences between VBA and VBscripts.  At first tools, references was grayed out but I was able to fix that.  Also found a couple other typos but thanks for the spot on Kandler.  Now I am getting a compile error at the range portion of “myPara = oDocRange(0, oWord.Selection.Characters(39).Range.End).Characters.Count”

The characters section of that was where I kind of went off script from the video.  So not sure if I did it correctly.  Sorry for clueless questions but really appreciate the help!
